# how to get some field of current week data and some of next 7 days data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

[image: Sample data]Hi everyone i have tried to write query so i want result as weekly_outstanding column data in current week and recover column get next 7 days data.
3 input paramter team_id, week_start_date, week_end_date
output as expected weekly_outstanding column data based on input paramter and recovery data comes from next 7 days
for ex- i have select date between 2022-03-28 to 2022-04-03 in input parameter so weekly_outstanding data comes from this week and recovery comes from next week

```
SELECT sum(weekly_outstanding) as last_week_os, sum(recovery)  FROM `fleet_driver_dash_weekly` WHERE team_id=1 and (week_start_date='2022-03-28' and week_end_date='2022-04-03'
```

Comment: Could you please give some additional details like table structure, sample data and exp output etc. Also is it "some" or "sum" in the question?

Comment: @AbishekVK i have updated my question, basically i have total 2 column 1- weekly_outstanding and 2- recovery, but i want result weekly_outstanding from current which week i have used in parameter and record is next 7 days

Comment: Unless you show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE fleet_driver_dash_weekly` , a few rows of sample data, and a sample of the result set you require, any help we give you will necessarily be based on guesses. That's a waste of our time and yours. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this, not sure if this solve your problem. can modify if you could share some sample data and expected output.

```
SELECT sum(weekly_outstanding) as last_week_os
, sum(recovery) over (order by week_start_date asc ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 7 
FOLLOWING)
FROM `fleet_driver_dash_weekly` WHERE team_id=1 ;
```

Comment: not getting proper output, also i have updated my question so u can better understand